# How to test the document.referrer on local?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I try to test the use of `document.referrer` in two local HTML pages but it doesn't work.

Here is my code:

HTML1:

```
<body>
  <button type="button" name="button" onclick="go()">go!</button>
  <a href="123.html">go with a</a>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function go() {
    location.assign('123.html')
  }
</script>
```

HTML2(123.html):

```
<body>
  <button type="button" name="button" onclick="gopre()">back</button>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function gopre() {
    location.assign(document.referrer);
    //console.log(document.referrer);//it's null
  }
</script>
```

Does `document.referrer` work locally? How should I use it?

Answer (score 1):

maybe cannot.

the `document.referrer` will be assigned by Browser and it will be stored by Browser.

The solution is that you could start a `Quick Start` web server.

Answer (score 0):

Now I know why it can not work locally,because it relies on HTTP requests to work,

you can not use `document.referrer` even in an HTTP page jumped from an HTTPS page!